# How to represent the "Shift" key?

Tags: symbols, arrows

I am struggling to represent the "Shift" key. This is my best attempt so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keystroke}
\usepackage[arrows]{boisik}

\begin{document}
Current solution: \keystroke{$\upwhitearrow$ Shift}
\end{document}
```

[image: Current solution]

I'm still not happy with the result as the up arrow is quite different from that of a real keyboard:

[image: Real shift key]

I also tried to find a more similar up arrow using [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to no avail:

[image: Detexify]

How could I get a more realistic representation of the "Shift" key? (I'm using pdfLaTex.)

Comment: I suppose the `\Shift` macro is not close enough to the arrow you want?

Comment: @samcarter :Thank you for your suggestion, I was not aware of the existence of the `\Shift` macro. But my current solution is closer to the desired result than yours.

Comment: Anyway if you want to use this key often, it might be better to redefine the definition of `\Shift` with whatever solution you choose (hint: only the duck is a valid choice :).

Comment: The one on my keyboard here looks much more like `\uparrow` -- there's quite a lot of variety

Comment: Thank you Fran, TeXnician and marmot for your suggestions. All the approaches you proposed are fine, but in order to close this question I have to accept one answer, and the winner is... @marmot! as his/her solution is the one which best fit my needs (although using TikZ for this is admittedly a bit of overkill).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For just this purpose this will be an overkill, but if you have many keyboards that you wish to recreate, it might be worthwhile considering using Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keystroke}
\usepackage[arrows]{boisik}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
Current solution: \keystroke{$\upwhitearrow$ Shift}

Alternative solution: \keystroke{\tikz{%
\node[single arrow,draw,shape border rotate=90,scale=0.3,minimum height=20pt](arrow){};
\node[right=5pt of arrow,font=\sffamily,inner sep=0pt](shift){Shift};
\path(shift.north)--++(0,2pt);}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why would one do this? This is IMHO the easiest way to also get the `duck` key. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keystroke}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\keystroke{\tikz{%
\begin{scope}[scale=0.15,local bounding box=duck]
\duck
\end{scope}
\node[right=5pt of duck,yshift=1pt,font=\sffamily,inner sep=0pt](shift) {duck};
\path(shift.north)--++(0,2pt);}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where can I get a keyboard with this key?????

Comment: @samcarter Are you kidding me? Are you implying your keyboard does not have this key? So you *really* type `\ ` `d` `u` `c` `k` just to get a duck? ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately yes - I have to deal with an inferior model that aims at input for humans. It has neither a duck nor a marmot key!

Comment: @samcarter Oh no! That's a scandal. You should seriously consider suing the seller.

Comment: Or I should complain with the people from worker protection - there must be regulations against this!

Comment: @samcarter Judging from the OP's profile pic, one may assume that (s)he was really looking for a duck key, which is clearly much more important than a boring shift. ;-)

Comment: :) good reasoning!

Comment: @samcarter Probably the manufacturer of your keyboard does provide a duck-patch. Would that be an option for you?

Comment: @UlrichDiez Totally :) I'll asap start an email: "Dear Apple, please sent the missing duck patch. It was missing upon delivery and without it the computer cannot be operated, but I ordered a working computer...."

Comment: This key is very useful when programming in languages that rely on Duck Typing.

Comment: @samcarter You could cut one out from yellow duck tape and add it onto the marmot key

Comment: @KJO You mean this tape: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47079496#47079496 ? :)

Comment: @samcarter Perfect what's the product number? Those are a bit big you need them about this size http://www.maxkeyboard.com/custom-art-icon-or-text-cherry-mx-keycaps.html or else you would need this enter key to add the shift function http://www.fentek-ind.com/images/kbklxwq2.jpg

Comment: Would it be possible to replace `\node[single arrow,draw,shape border rotate=90,scale=0.3,minimum height=20pt](arrow){};` by `\node[](arrow){\shift}`, being `\shift` the `menukeys` macro suggested by @TeXnician? I tried this but I got `! LaTeX Error: Command \Alt already defined.`

Comment: @Tonechas There seems to be an incompatibility between `menukeys` and `keystroke`. This prevents clean solutions of this type, I am afraid. However, one can tweak the parameters of `single arrows` shape to reproduce the symbol of TeXnician's answer. The parameters of this shape are explained on p. 717-718 of the pgfmanual, please let me know if you run into problems.

Answer (score 18):

Just as alternative a package-based approach (`menukeys`) which looks slightly different.

[image: menu keys]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{menukeys}

\begin{document}
\keys{\shift\ Shift}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

As there are already solutions with `keystrokes`, `menukeys` and ducks, I will try with `tcolorbox`. Bonus: the key is clickable.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\def\shift{\tcbox[beamer, on line, size=small,
toprule=.5pt, bottomrule=2pt, leftrule=.6pt, rightrule=1.5pt,
hyperref=sec:Shift,
frame style={upper left=yellow!40!black!40,
lower left=cyan!05!black!85,
upper right=yellow!10!black!70,
lower right=red!05!black},colupper=green!10!white,
colback=black!65]{\sffamily\rotatebox{90}{\Large\pointer} Shift
} }

\begin{document}
See the \shift section. 
\newpage
\section*{The shift key}
\label{sec:Shift}
This is the text about the Shift key
\end{document}
```